# Python 2 , re sub desVar( "rgt1" "vdd")

Tags: python, regex

Can someone help me on python re-pattern?

```
desVar(    "vrgt1"    "0"    )
desVar(    "vrgt0"    "vdd"    )
```

I want to have the `"0"` and `"vdd"` replaced...
I've tried :

```
re.sub('"vrg1".+\s"(.+)".+','vdd', string)
```

But it didn't work....

Comment: replaced by what? the Duke of Forest Hill? what about the 0 in the first position of the second tuple? your question is not clear.

Comment: `re.sub(r'("vrg[^"]*".+\s")(.+)"',r'\1vdd"', string)`

Comment: Is it a typo that you missed `t` in `vrgt1` for the `re.sub`?

Comment: there are many lines like these"0" "vdd" are the value I want to be replaced by any value.

Comment: I tried  re.sub(r'vrgt1[.]+"(\S)" ', 'vdd/2', string) still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't help to capture a group of characters to be replaced (`(.+)` in your original try); instead, you can capture the group of characters to keep (`(vrgt1.+")` below), and re-insert it into the replacement (with `\1`):

```
>>> print string

desVar(    "vrgt1"    "0"    )
desVar(    "vrgt0"    "vdd"    )

>>> print re.sub(r'(vrgt1.+").+"', r'\1vdd"', string) 

desVar(    "vrgt1"    "vdd"    )
desVar(    "vrgt0"    "vdd"    )
```